# flutter : Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock

Tags: flutter, dart

this   error is frustrating

i used to run older  flutter version  in **hp pavilion g6 notebook** before  but  right  now , it  won't  even  work ,  what's changed .every flutter command i type , it turn  out to be this error  for days, no changes !

```
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...

At line:1 char:1
+ flutter doctor
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Waiting for ano...startup lock...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

1. i tried killing all Flutter processes. On Windows,
   i used the command

```
taskkill /F /IM dart.exe
```

2. in a Command Prompt or PowerShell window1.
   i also tried removing the lockfile located at

```
 <YOUR FLUTTER FOLDER>/bin/cache/lockfile.
```

3. i turned off their antivirus software.
4. i tried running the

```
flutter clean
```

command

5. Sad story  is i even
   reset  my pc ,  not changes
6. i Closed and reopened my IDE to make sure there are no lingering processes
7. i Verified that my system's environment variables, especially the PATH variable, are correctly configured to point to the Flutter SDK's bin directory.
8. Reinstall Flutter multiple time

What’d I Miss ?????????

Comment: What flutter version is that?

Comment: Have you tried running `flutter doctor` outside your IDE? (don't even start IDE) Maybe IDE is at fault here, doing something with Flutter in background, like updating etc.